# If the value of a certain key does not exist in the object add this element to object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this array:

```
myArray=[
{name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
{name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
{name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
{name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
]
```

I wanna see if `name: 'bob'` does not exist in the object add `{name: 'bob', value: 'bob rogan'}` to the object. Currently I'm doing this but it adds 3 elements to the object:

```
    for (let hasan in myArray) {
        if (hasan.name !== "bob") {
          tempArray.push({name: 'bob', value: 'bob rogan'});
        }
    }
```

How can I add just one `{name: 'bob', value: 'bob rogan'}` element to the object if `name: 'bob'` doesn't exist using es6 magic?

Comment: `for..in` loop gets the key in each loop. So, `hasan` is index of the array not each object. You need to use `for..of` loop: `for (let hasan of myArray)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Array.some` check if there is an bob inside. It returns you either true or false. Later you use a simple `if` statement

```js
let myArray=[
{name: 'joe', value: 'joe rogan'},
{name: 'sarah', value: 'sarah rogan'},
{name: 'jack', value: 'jack rogan'},
{name: 'steph', value: 'steph rogan'}
]

let found = myArray.some(({name}) => name === "bob");

if(!found) myArray.push({ name: "bob", value: 'bob rogan' })

console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code for every element, if it is not equal to bob , it will add bob. what you need to do is to check the array if contains bob and after checking all the array it should add bob if not their.

```
// filter the array and return the element that contains bob in the result array if exists.
var result = myArray.filter(elem => elem.name == 'bob');
// if the result array is empty then add 'bob'
if(result.length == 0){
myArray.push({name: 'bob', value: 'bob rogan'});
}
```